# Minimum payload for push notification?

Tags: ios, windows-phone-7, blackberry, apple-push-notifications, android-c2dm

Is there a minimum payload size for the push notification service for the various mobile platforms like Android, iOS, Blackberry and Windows Phone 7?

I want to know if I were to send a very short message, would it be rejected.

Thanks,
Hend

Comment: I think it's a good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WP7 (from MSDN):

> The maximum size of a notification is 1 KB for the header and 3 KB for
>   the payload. Notifications exceeding these limits will be discarded
>   and a WebException with a status of WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError
>   will be raised

Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558(v=VS.92).aspx

EDIT: Just reread the question and realised you were asking for a minimum. Don't really know why you would be interested in that but there is no minimum in WP7.

Comment: I want to know if I were to send a very short message, would it be rejected.

Comment: Not in WP7. Not sure about the other platforms.

Answer (score 2):

From Apples [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) of push notification

> The maximum size allowed for a notification payload is 256 bytes;
>   Apple Push Notification Service refuses any notification that exceeds
>   this limit.

Anything over 256 bytes, your are off..Anything less no problem..Not sure about other platforms